# Replace the values ​of one array based on the values in another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
$priceYear = Array ( 
       [AZ] => Array 
             ( 
               [1] => 2020 
               [2] => 2020 
             ) 
       [BY] => Array 
             ( 
               [0] => 2020 
               [1] => 2020 
             ) 
       [CX] => Array 
             ( 
               [1] => 2020 
               [2] => 2020 
               [3] => 2020 
             ) 
       [DW] => Array 
             ( 
               [106] => 2019 
               [107] => 2019 
               [108] => 2019
             )
      )
```

And another array with this

```
$array = Array ( 
       [0] => Array 
             ( 
               [YEAR] => 2018 
               [VALUE_AMDON] => 55 
             ) 
       [1] => Array 
             ( 
               [YEAR] => 2019
               [VALUE_AMDON] => 57
             ) 
       [2] => Array 
             ( 
               [YEAR] => 2020 
               [VALUE_AMDON] => 59
             ) 
      )
```

And I want to replace with the VALUE_AMDON if value from $priceYear == YEAR

So the output should look like this

```
$priceYear = Array ( 
                    [AZ] => Array 
                          ( 
                            [1] => 59 
                            [2] => 59
                          ) 
                    [BY] => Array 
                          ( 
                            [0] => 59
                            [1] => 59 
                          ) 
                    [CX] => Array 
                          ( 
                            [1] => 59
                            [2] => 59 
                            [3] => 59 
                          ) 
                    [DW] => Array 
                          ( 
                            [106] => 57
                            [107] => 57 
                            [108] => 57
                          )
             )
```

I'm doing it like this

```
function replace($var){
    global $array;
    for ($u=0; $u <sizeof($array) ; $u++) { 
        if ($var == $array[$u]['YEAR']){
            return $array[$u]['VALUE_AMDON'];
        }else{
            return $var;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($priceYear as $key => $value) {
    $priceYear[$key] = array_map('replace', $value);
}
```

But unfortunately it is not working, it is returning the initial array

If someone can help me, looks like the error is very dumb but i'm not seeing it :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no direct link between the keys of the arrays, the easiest way to do this is to use nested loops.

You just need to loop through your `$priceYear` array and check each of the "year" value acainst the `YEAR` value in `$array`. If they match, you can replace just that value in your `$priceYear` array.

The code below is commented to tell you what each line is doing:

```
// 1. loop through the nested arrays in $priceYear
foreach ($priceYear as $key => $price_years_array) {
    foreach ($price_years_array as $index => $price_years_value) {

        // 2. Create a variable to store the new value for the year in this $priceYear array, 
        // initialised to 0 (your specified default)
        $new_year = 0;

        // 3. check each year in your $array
        foreach ($array as $replacement_values){

            // 4. if $replacement_values has a YEAR and VALUE_AMDON...
            //    and $price_years_value matches the value in YEAR...
            if( $replacement_values['YEAR'] && $replacement_values['VALUE_AMDON']
                && $replacement_values['YEAR'] == $price_years_value){

                    // 5. store this in our $new_year variable
                    $new_year = $replacement_values['VALUE_AMDON'];
             }
        }
        
        // 6. after checking all years in $array, it we found a match it will be in $new_year
        // otherwise it will still be 0. 
        // Now simple set this value  - we can access this directly using $key and $index
        $priceYear[$key][$index] = $new_year;
    }
}
var_dump($priceYear);
```

Sample Data using years that don't exist:

```
$priceYear = array(
    'AZ' => array( 1 => 2021, 2 => 2020), // <-- 2021 doesn't exist in $array
    'BY' => array( 0 => 2020, 1 => 2016), // <-- 2016 doesn't exist in $array
    'CX' => array(1 => 2020, 2 => 2020, 3 => 2020),
    'DW' => array(106 => 2019, 107 => 2019, 108 => 2019)
);

$array = array(
    array('YEAR' => 2018, 'VALUE_AMDON' => 55),
    array('YEAR' => 2019, 'VALUE_AMDON' => 57),
    array('YEAR' => 2020, 'VALUE_AMDON' => 59)
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [AZ] => Array
        (
            [1] => 0       // <-- value is 0 because year didn't exist in $array
            [2] => 59
        )
    [BY] => Array
        (
            [0] => 59
            [1] => 0       // <-- value is 0 because year didn't exist in $array
        ) 
    [CX] => Array
        (
            [1] => 59
            [2] => 59
            [3] => 59
        )
    [DW] => Array
        (
            [106] => 57
            [107] => 57
            [108] => 57
        )
)
```

Comment: Ty, how I make that if $replacement_values['YEAR'] != $price_years_value or even that YEAR doesn't exist $priceYear = 0

Comment: @Legion If none of the values of `YEAR` exist in `$priceYear`, then no change is made. At the moment this code uses `$priceYear` as the basis and only changes the year in it if it has a match in `$array` - otherwose nothing changes.  So you want to change the year in `$priceYear` it to the value in `$array` if a match is found, and `0`  otherwise - is that correct?

Comment: @Legion I've updated my answer with detailed comments and sample data to show it working

Comment: @Legion No problem! Your question showed a decent attempt at doing it yourself so that gives us something to work with and so you have a better chance if getting a solution here :) Just for future, it's best to include all requirements in the question (such as the need for 0 for non-matching years) so that you get the answer you need first time - people might not be online after they answer to see any changes :)

Comment: Yes, you are right that was my bad, I glad that you help me, ty :3

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with array functions like array_column and array_search check below:

```
$array_year = array_column($array, "YEAR");
foreach($priceYear as $key => $val){
    foreach($val as $innerkey => $innerval){
        // Below If year exist in $array_year function return key of $array_year else return false
        $isExistKey = array_search($innerval, $array_year);
        if($isExistKey !== FALSE){
            $priceYear[ $key ][ $innerkey ] = $array[ $isExistKey ]["VALUE_AMDON"];
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($priceYear);
```

Check the output here: https://paiza.io/projects/gUNihGow6-CWO0eqWpEtxg?language=php